# Restrict iOS share extension only to Safari

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

Currently in my NSExtensionActivationRule, is only this value:

```
NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount = 1
```

But my share extension is also visible in Chrome, is there a way to restrict share extension to be visible only in Safari ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is :

You need to replace

> NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount

with

> NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount

After that, your extension will be visible only in Safari.